# Background Not Expanding

Tags: css, background, containers, background-color, repeat

Alright, I am designing a website using XHTML 1.0 Strict and CSS 1,2,3. And, I have a container for the page, that contains every div within the container, I have min-height specified on the container to ensure expanding of the page.

But, I have another container within the page container that contains a content div and sidebar div and all 3 of the containers inside the content container are set to height: inherit; and all have a min-height.

On the container which includes both the content and sidebar divs, I have a background gradient image which is positioned at the top and center, but am also calling out a background color which I want to continue as a sort-of fade-out effect, which would leave the container open for page expansion.

But, the problem is, the color is not repeating all the way down within the container.

You may view the design below, it is linked with a pretty well organized External Style Sheet. As well as the HTML page being well organized.

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/kolja/

Thank you very much StackOverflow,
I hope to hear from someone very soon,
Aaron Brewer

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. I see the gradient on the #content-container - I'm not sure what you mean by the color not repeating all the way down. The gradient is vertical, so once it goes to a color, it just stays that color to the bottom of the container. Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if i understood your problem.

But adding:

this

```
float: left;
```

to this:

```
#content-container
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

That link gave me a 404 Page not found.

Perhaps you mean that you want to stretch the background-image using css? In that case I can tell you that such a thing is impossible. You cannot stretch css background images.

Usually when you want a gradient background you make a sufficiently long gradient and fill the rest of the background with the ending color of the gradient.

CSS 3 supports defining gradients as colors. [W3C working draft of gradients.](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#gradients)

Comment: Actually, that's not entirely true. There is a `background-size` property in CSS3. It's support is still a little sketchy, though, especially if you have to support anything but the absolute latest of every browser. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html#t010